# Installing zeligverse in R 4.0.2

Tags: r, installation, r-zelig

I'm trying to use plot.ci function in the zelig library but apparently Zelig is not supported with R 4.0.2. I'm trying to see if there is a work around to access these functions or if I just can't use this library until they make the appropriate updates. Please help.

Ethan

Error message below:

```
> install.packages('zeligverse')

WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ethan/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘zeligverse’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)
```

Comment: So i'm not also looking for the source code for plot.ci with this package as that would solve my problem more easily.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this package has been removed from CRAN's repository, meaning you can't install it like this anymore - you have to install it manually. This is explained on their website, and has download links for manual installation that have been archived:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zeligverse/index.html

You will also have to install the following dependencies (packages it requires) to install it correctly:
'Amelia', 'MatchIt', 'WhatIf', 'Zelig', 'ZeligChoice', 'ZeligEI'

The Zelig package that is currently available appears to support the function you mentioned. You can install it with:

```
install.packages("Zelig")
```

Comment: install.packages("Zelig") doesn't work on R >= 4.0